# adb shell cmd overlay resets to it's previous state (doesn't activate) after reboot

Tags: overlay, android-source, gesture, android-11, android-navigation-bar

I'm trying to switch between `gestural` and `threebutton` navigation using

`cmd overlay enable com.android.internal.systemui.navbar.gestural`

and

`cmd overlay enable com.android.internal.systemui.navbar.threebutton`

or via `system-->gestures-->system navigation` and then selecting `gesture navigation` and `3-button navigation`.

I checked the changes using -
`cmd overlay list --user current`  and I was able to see the exact changes made.

But when i reboot my android device, it just reverts back to the previous selected navigation; rarely (after 5-6 tries) the changes made remain after reboot.

Example: If my present selection is threebutton and I change it to gestural, then after reboot it goes back to threebutton or sometimes (after 5-6 tries and reboots), it stays as gestural.

How do i keep the changes permanent even after reboot??

Answer (score -1):

I also have the same issue. The changes made using the adb cmd overlay does not remain after reboot. However, in some forums, i saw that the changes still stayed for some even after reboot but they were probably running android 10. I am currently running Android 11. I don't really know if they changed this feature with android upgrades.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).